# Graph API: get user who comment on page post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm trying to get all the comments of page post with name of who comment using this query:

```bash
{post_id}/comments?fields=from,message
```

but it doesn't return the `from` field

I'm using v16.0 of Facebook graph API.

my app was reviewed for this permissions  `pages_read_user_content, pages_read_engagement,pages_show_list`, I'm using page access token and the app is in live mode but nothing

is there anything I'm missing ?

i will be thankful for any help

i tried to inspect other apps are using this functionality and i believe we are requesting the same permission from user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get user info from comments you need:

1. Have business verified
2. have approved permissions with advanced access for  `pages_read_user_content, pages_read_engagement,pages_show_list`
3. have approved permissions with advanced access for  `Business Asset User Profile Access`
4. Correct Privacy and Terms of service published

And a lot of patience... we send my app 12 times before approved the last permission.

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/business-asset-user-profile-access/

Comment: I have completed the initial two tasks and the final task; however, I was not aware of the `Business Asset User Profile Access` permission, which I believe may be the cause of the issue. i will back to your answer to confirm if it work, thanks .

Comment: i'm not sure if  `Business Asset User Profile Access` permission is really needed for viewing comment owner, i submit permission request twice and the refused it

Comment: Once this permission was approved, I was able to retrieve the 'from' field, as I mentioned earlier. I had submitted my app 12 times before it was finally approved.
i use this caption:
"We use the permission to list the posts from the selected page and to obtain the list of users who commented on the post along with the name and PSID of the person who posted the comment."

Comment: I'm in my third time i still need another 9 times LOL

Comment: Thank you very much, `Business Asset User Profile Access` permission it was what i'm missing to get the `from` field in comments, and it wasn't accessible from public becuase i didn't get `Access verification`

Answer (score 0):

to get user info you have to review your facebook app and get advance access of the permission then after you will get that data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response 

as i said 

`my app was reviewed for this permissions pages_read_user_content, pages_read_engagement,pages_show_list`

and they approved my permissions requests, but i still can't get the needed data or publish my app